# Running a function after the DOM of an Angular Component has changed, similar to ngAfterViewInit

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a component that instantiates a bunch of directives based on an input. In the example below (not the real code, but boiled down as much as I could to illustrate the question), the component gets config as an `Input()`, uses a `MyService` to turn that into `this.fields`, and the `dynamicField` directive then renders the actual fields in the component.
After all the fields have been rendered by the directive, I want to `doSomething()`. I implemented that using `ngAfterViewInit()` which works well.

Now the problem: later on, I want to trigger a change of `this.fields` is some components get removed and others get added from the component. But how can I run doSomething() again, after all the directives have been rendered again? `ngAfterViewinit()` doesn't get triggered in this case.

```
import { MyService } from './myService.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'mycomp',
    template: '<ng-template *ngFor="let field of fields;" dynamicField [config]="field"></ngtemplate><button (click)="myTrigger()">Trigger</button>'
})
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit{

    @Input() config: object;
    fields: object[];

    constructor(myService: MyService){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.fields = this.myService.getFields(this.config);
    }

    myTrigger(){
        this.fields.pop();
        this.fields.push({'id': 'someotherfield', 'label':'someotherfield'})
    }

    doSomething() {
        console.log('dosomething');
    }

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        doSomething();
    }


}
```

Comment: `this.myService.getFields(this.config)` this has to be an observable, so you can subscribe in the `onInit` and whenever the data is changed, the component will be rendered again

Comment: `ngDoCheck()` try to call function in it

Comment: @Jacopo Sciampi as you can see, the trigger doesn't come from a change to the config, but rather is triggered inside the Component. (in the example by a button click). So that won't help me in this case.

Comment: is there any reason that you were not calling doSomething method inside myTrigger() method?

Comment: @JacopoSciampi (sorry can't edit the comment anymore)

Comment: @Chellappan yes, because it needs to be run after all the child components (directives) have finalized loading. This happens asynchronously. If I do what you suggest, doSomething() gets run before some or all of the directives have been rendered and added to the DOM. But the ngAfterViewChecked function seems to do what I need.

Comment: ngAfterViewInit() is called after the view is initially rendered.that is a reason it is not being called second time when the value change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
import { Component, AfterViewChecked, OnInit} from '@angular/core';


export class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked, OnInit{


     ngAfterViewChecked(){
         doSomething();
     }

}
```

Comment: Good idea. AfterViewChecked gets triggered a little more often then I'd like (other changes to the Component can trigger it too). But it definitely gets run after all the child views of the directives have rendered, also after changes to the DOM that cause changes to the child views. So with some extra intelligence, I can make it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Delaying execution until the next tick using setTimeout might work:

```
myTrigger(){
  this.fields.pop();
  this.fields.push({'id': 'someotherfield', 'label':'someotherfield'})
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.doSomething()
  })
}
```